# Dynamic linking entire .blend file

Tags: linked-data

Using dynamic linking, how can all the data from one .blend file be linked into another? The usual Ctrl Alt O method will lead me to a directory of components within a selected .blend file. For example, I can import a mesh or group, but neither would link with materials applied.

Comment: You should perhaps import objects, not meshes directly. The best/fastest way to import all from another .blend could be to just import all "scenes" (often there's only one).

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking but I think the append option might work. It is in the file menu.

Comment: Append and link will not give me everything. If I append or link a mesh, object, or group, it will not come with any material. I want all the data to be there.

Comment: Okay, this is making some progress. All required data is there if a scene is linked, but since it creates a separate scene in the main project file, I can't actually incorporate it into the original scene. Tried Ctrl C and then Ctrl V into the original scene, but it doesn't work. Plus, I assume that creates local data and defeats the purpose of linking. But this is a step in the right direction, it would seem.

Comment: @Hiigaran once linked the new scene, switch to its instance in the file, select all needed object and make links to the other, original, scene where you need to use them (CTRL-L => object to scene => "scene"), there you can make proxies for them if you need to move, scale, rotate them...

Comment: @Hiigaran anyway, linking/appending even single objects and even single meshes DOES link/append their materials also...

Comment: @m.ardito Okay, looks like it's working. Now if I follow your method for, say 20 different objects, that would mean I have 20 different scenes, in addition to the main scene, what should I be doing if one of those objects needs to be duplicated multiple times?

Comment: no, you get a new scene only if you link/append a scene. Then you can make all or selected linked scene objects themselves linked to you "local" scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, we can't go on discussing this in comments...

As said if you need to append/link "all" of a .blend file, it's better to append/link an entire scene: here is an example for linking.

[image]

As you see, I linked a scene from another file, then from the linked scene in my new file, I made links for all objects in my "local" scene.

To be able to transform one of them (in object mode), add modifiers, etc, I had to make a proxy.

Another example shows how linking a single mesh (not even an object) also links its material:

[image]
Appending/linking just a mesh, you can't see it, until is assigned to an object, but it's there (technically is called "orphan data"), and its material also (also linked).

Comment: Ignoring the second part of your answer regarding the mesh linking for a moment...I'm with you so far, up to making a proxy. I got confused with your comment in my question, however. So if I follow your answer and I'm up to the part about making a proxy (which I assume I make a proxy for every object and children of parent objects from the linked scene), I should be ready to add additional duplicates of the linked object, yes? What should I do here?

Comment: when you have the proxy, you can duplicate it as usual: duplicate linked (ALT-D) which gives you another proxy, or regular duplicate (SHIFT -D) which makes a duplicate of the proxy, but "local", no more linked (that means you can alter its mesh in edit mode too)...

Comment: Okay. Now for one last question (hopefully). After linking the scene, then making links to the original scene, I noticed that if I edit the original external file, nothing happened in the main project. I tried scaling the object in the external file, saving, then closing and reopening the main project where the external file was linked in to, but the one I made a proxy of did not change. Thoughts?

Comment: It does, until you proxy it. But you have to reload the linking file, after editing the linked original one. When you proxy, you make a local transforms object mode reference, and thus it is no more updated. But if you delete the proxy instantly the linked object gets the update. That's the whole point of a proxy here: "let me use this object here indipendently",

Comment: So there's no way to create components in external files, and have them update in a main project file at any time you make changes, if those components have been positioned, scaled and/or rotated after being linked? After making changes to those external files, you would need to delete any proxied components in the main project, relink, and reposition/scale/rotate?

Comment: I think yes, but you're putting too many questions in one... the title was about another, more general thing, this can't be a tutorial...  better open a new specific one... me or someone else will answer there.